# Using a variable as a setting name

Tags: c#, application-settings

Currently I got the following:

```
textBoxTimer5.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Timer5_Duration;
```

And my goal is to remove the number and get it from the sender, so I would like something like:

```
var settingName = "Timer" + number + "_duration";
textBoxTimer.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.settingName;
```

This is repetitive code that I am trying to optimize.

I tried with the following:

```
var settingName = "Timer" + number + "_duration";
textBoxTimer.Text = Properties.Settings.Default[settingName];
```

But it cannot save nor get what's saved in the settings that way.

Would there be a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: When you try to retrieve it, what's happening? Error? null result?

Comment: Oh the typo was only when I typed it here... I did not copy/paste. I verified and it was fine in the code, I'll get you the exact error.

Comment: I just made additional tests, after further testing, I was opening the wrong user.config file, I have one for debug and one for release and I was opening the release one while my debugger was set to run on debug. I would like to apologize for this. Everything is behaving correctly.